# How to deploy Spring Boot application to different URL on Tomcat?

Tags: spring, maven, tomcat, deployment

I am building and deploying my Spring Boot application into Tomcat with `mvn tomcat:deploy` and with this configuration:

```
<build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    <plugins>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <url>http://127.0.0.1:8080/manager/text</url>
                <server>tomcat</server>
                <path>/${project.build.finalName}</path>
                <username>admin</username>
                <password>password</password>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
```

Application runs then at `/${project.artifactId}`. I would like to deploy the application to the another URL, ideally to set target URL while I call Maven deploy command. Is it possible? If so, how can I achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

You can override maven properties from command line with -D option.

To specify another url for your app the interesting properties are `maven.tomcat.port` and `maven.tomcat.path`.

The following command line should do the trick :

```
mvn -Dmaven.tomcat.port=8181 -Dmaven.tomcat.path=/custom tomcat:deploy
```

Comment: It doesn't work, the deploy path is the same as usual.